# Jsoup is not detecting a span

Tags: java, android

I want to parse this website:

```
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=B0792KTHKJ
```

and get `a-offscreen` span class but Jsoup is not detecting it for some reason here is the source code:

```
final String PRICE_QUERY = "a-offscreen";
Document document;
                document = Jsoup.connect(currentPage).get();

                String price;

                Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass(PRICE_QUERY);  
                        price = elements.text();
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: Price: "+price);
```

Comment: the code looks good. What do you mean it is not detecting?

Comment: @Simple WebDesigner  I ran your code and it's working fine! except that the className you're searching for is not present in the document result! so if you print the document out first and manually use a Ctrl+f to find "a-offscreen" it is not present in the document result! but you can search for something else like "nav-right" then it will show up! so maybe the class you need is been encrypted or something else but it's just not present, but your code is fine apparently .

Comment: @nupadhyaya what Im trying to say is that `a-offscreen` span class have text $49.99 but I don't get that text back in log

Comment: @W.Seun You mean in inspection tab in chrome? if so span class `a-offscreen` does show up when I search, thats why I'm asking the class do show up in the browser but Jsoup is not detecting it

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner you're right it does show up when you inspect! which is where I am guessing if it might have been encrypted somehow, I'm not sure anyway.

Comment: @W.Seun so do you know another way to obtain the span or another way to get the price of a product, the problem is amazon's AWS api is hard to work with you need associate id and aws key